# Как правильно сделать One to one or zero в fluent api?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть 2 объекта которые должны друг от друга зависеть, но один из них может отсутствовать при заполнении пишет:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EventProfileUserId', table 'mining-university.dbo.Meetups'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EventProfileUserId', table 'mining-university.dbo.Speakers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated. The statement has been terminated
```

Вот код, я еще сделал вторую часть, иначе у в другом объекте ссылка будет отсутствовать, что не так настроено?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EventProfileUser>()
.HasOne(a => a.Meetup)
.WithOne(b => b.EventProfileUser)
.HasForeignKey<Meetup>(b => b.EventProfileUserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Speaker>()
.HasOne(a => a.EventProfileUser)
.WithOne(b => b.Speaker)
.HasForeignKey<EventProfileUser>(b => b.SpeakerId);
```

Сам объект:

```
public class EventProfileUser
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime Registration { get; set; }
    public bool Activity { get; set; }

    public string MeetupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Meetup Meetup { get; set; }

    public string SpeakerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Speaker Speaker { get; set; }
}

public class Meetup
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EventProfileUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual EventProfileUser EventProfileUser { get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте `.HasOptional` + `.WithOptionalPrincipal` - см. например https://stackoverflow.com/q/14701378/5752652 на en so

Comment: А, [этого уже нет](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35562483/5752652) в core.

Comment: @AK, Показывает платформу Core